# Undo delete / move to trash in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

In Thunderbird, I press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to move a message to my Trash.

How can I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> (undo) to restore the deleted message?

I am using IMAP if it makes any difference.

Comment: Summary of accepted answer: press F5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience (I also just tried this with two different IMAP accounts):

1. Pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> when I have selected a message in my INBOX moves the message to the Trash folder.
2. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> does move the message back to the INBOX.
3. A message in the status bar confirms something has happened: "Deleted 1 message from Trash".
4. However, the view is not refreshed right away, and I still don't see it in my INBOX.
5. I either wait some time or I explicitly trigger a refresh by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or I select a different folder and then go back to the INBOX.
6. The deleted and subsequently undeleted message is shown back in its place after a second or so.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> also works if I visit a different folder after deleting the message. In that case, going back to the INBOX triggers a refresh and the message reappears.