# How to undo moving a message to an archive in Thunderbird?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, shortcuts, email-client, undo

In Thunderbird you can archive a message if you hit <kbd>a</kbd>.

For example, in the Mail app on macOS there is an option to undo the last action including archiving.

Is it possible to do the same in Thunderbird? Pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this related question: [Undo delete / move to trash in Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/1183909/thunderbird-undo-delete-move-to-trash?rq=1).

From what I learned from that, it seems to me like <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does work, but doesn't display the changes. Pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> afterwards worked for me.